# CSS grid + srcset + sizes work with multiple widths and screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images, srcset

I have a 14 column css grid that's centered on the page on desktop. All my images are set to `max-width: 100%` so the width is dependent on the width of the column container.

```
<img src="image_path.jpg&s=image-390"
     srcset="image_path.jpg&s=image-390 390w,
             image_path.jpg&s=image-585 585w,
             image_path.jpg&s=image-780 780w,
             image_path.jpg&s=image-1170 1170w,
             image_path.jpg&s=image-1560 1560w,
     sizes="(min-width: 1023px) 300px, 100vw">
```

On desktops the width of the image in the column is 300px (4 col) but why is it serving up the 585 image when I check in the network tab on my Macbook Pro that has a device ratio of 2? Shouldn't it be 780? It's 300*2=600 so the next image up is 780 right? Also if I change it to 380px for some reason it pulls the 780 image (< 379px pulls 585) but why? It seems so random to me.

Answer (score 0):

Found lazysizes plugin fixes my problem.